# Discord JS - delete a reply message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to delete certain message with certain event like this:

```
await interaction.reply({ content: `content` })
            .then(message => {
                console.log(message);
                client.on('messageDelete', async () => {
                    await message.delete();
                });
            });
```

But I get **undefined** in a console.log as a message. What is wrong? I already done the message delition with .then() and it worked, but now something is wrong. Maybe because it is reply, not just plain message?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a reply to an interaction by using [deleteReply()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseCommandInteraction?scrollTo=deleteReply)

```
// Delete the reply to this interaction
interaction.deleteReply()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```